# Get return value of function when last called, without calling it again

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am new to using gdb.

I have a function, which I will call a() that gives a different value every time it is called. Another function add_to_array uses a() as a parameter. Here is an example:

```
add_to_array(a())
add_to_array(a())
add_to_array(a())
```

How could I see what the return values of a() were each time it was called?

Comment: if you are only interested in the return value of `a()` you could add a breakpoint in add_to_array and check the parameter value ?

Comment: How could I add a breakpoint to all add_to_array iterations?

Comment: Go to the first line of source in `add_to_array` and set a breakpoint. How else would you think you would do it?

Comment: I'm very sorry yes I did know that. How could I see the paramater values though?

Comment: That depends on how `add_to_array` was declared. For example, if it's `void add_to_array(int x)`, then you would look at the value of `x` from within `add_to_array`.

Comment: look at the [gdb manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html), using the command `break add_to_array` should work, then when at the location `print parameter`

Comment: I don't understand why you did not simply load the return into a temp variable? It's a very good idea to avoid compound expressions as a default design, just to make debugging easier.  Clever code generates clever bugs:(

Answer (score 1):

> How could I see what the return values of a() were each time it was called?

If you are currently stopped before e.g. the last call to `add_to_array()`, and are interested in what value the first call to `a()` returned, the *only* way to know that (with GDB) is to examine what's in the array (to which `add_to_array()` adds values). GDB can't "go back in time" and can't keep track of every value that ever changed.

But if you just want to observe these values on re-run of the program, simply set a breakpoint on `add_to_array`, and (if your program is built with debug info -- usually the `-g` flag), GDB will stop and print the parameter value every time.

You may also be interested in a [replay debugger](https://rr-project.org/), which *can* go back in time and which can answer the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Employed Russian*'s excellent answer, you could instrument the code this way:

```
#define VALUES_HISTORY_LEN  65536
int a_values_history[VALUES_HISTORY_LEN];
int a_values_index;
int add_values_history[VALUES_HISTORY_LEN];
int add_values_index;

// this will store up to VALUES_HISTORY_LEN values previously returned by a()
#define a() (a_values_history[a_values_index++ % VALUES_HISTORY_LEN] = (a)())

// this will store up to VALUES_HISTORY_LEN values previously passed to add_to_array()
#define add_to_array(x)  (add_to_array)(add_values_history[add_values_index++ % VALUES_HISTORY_LEN] = (x))
```

Answer (score 0):

> How could I see what the return values of a() were each time it was called?

You can:

1. Stop at the first call to `add_to_array(a())`
2. Step into with `step` command. You will step into `a()` call at first because you can't step into `add_to_array()` before it's argument is evaluated
3. Finish `a()` call with `finish` command. The result of the call will be printed for you as described in [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html):

> Continue running until just after function in the selected stack frame returns. Print the returned value (if any).

Repeat these 3 steps for 2 remaining `add_to_array(a())` calls.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. What does this method add to "set break on `add_to_array()`"?

Comment: It allows not to set a breakpoint (and not delete it later), that is avoid managing breakpoints. However, both ways are applicable, this one is just an alternative.

Comment: I see. In that case, repeatedly setting a _temporary_ breakpoint with `tb add_to_array()` seems like a better approach.